# Using Jest to test Jquery that calls PHP ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jestjs

I have a Javascript file with a function I'm trying to test. All the function does is make a jQuery post request to a PHP ajax file (see code)

```
function loadTeams(clubID){

var data = {
    action: 'loadClubTeams',
    clubID: clubID
};

return jQuery.post('/ajax/calendar_ajax.php', data);
}
```

I have a mock set up in my `/__mocks__/` dir as such:

```
<?php

$teams = array(
    array(
        "Name" => "Team 1",
        "ClubID" => 34
    ),
    array(
        "Name" => "Team 2",
        "ClubID" => 34
    ),
    array(
        "Name" => "Team 3",
        "ClubID" => 35
    )
);
$response = array();
if($_REQUEST['action'] == "loadClubTeams"){
    foreach($teams as $team){
        if($team['ClubID'] == $_REQUEST['ClubID']){
            array_push($response, $team);
        }
    }
}
return json_encode($response);
```

Here is my test file:

```
const assoc_cal = require('../../secure-htdocs/js/templates/association_calendar');
jest.mock('../../secure-htdocs/ajax/calendar_ajax.php');

    test("loadTeams returns Teams 1 and 2 when passed clubID 34", () =>{
        data = {action: "loadTeams", ClubID: 34};
        const expected = [
            {
                name: "Team 1",
                clubID: 34
            },
            {
                name: "Team 2",
                clubID: 34
            }
        ];
        expect(assoc_cal(data)).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(expected));
    });
```

But when I run my test, it still tries to call the real calendar_ajax.php file. I'm apparently setting up the mock incorrectly. Can anyone else out with this?

Comment: I don't know `jest`, but are you missing a `json_encode` in your php where you `return $response;` ... Should it be `return json_encode($response);` (thinking your mock uses json values, not PHP "Array" string)? ... or not. I don't understand that php file or where `$data` in `if($data['action'] = "loadClubTeams"){` comes from.

Comment: Thanks IncredibleHat. Made a couple changes based on that

Comment: But still doesn't work huh. Must be something in the .mock or test syntax (which I'm entirely unfamiliar with, sorry).